# Insert missing records by copying data from previous record

Tags: mysql

Insert Missing Record by copying data from previous record.

I want to fetch past one month data from MySQL database.
If record does not exists on particular date pervious record must be inserted.

Below Query which give past 1 month data:

```
select Date(TimeStamp),NodeName,CPUUtilization 
from xyz 
where timestamp >= last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month 
group by DATE(TimeStamp);
```

But missing records need to be inserted wit previous data

Actual Result:

```
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| Date(TimeStamp) | NodeName| CPUUtilization  |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| 2019-02-01      | Node   |          16.82 |
| 2019-02-02      | Node   |          16.84 |
| 2019-02-04      | Node   |             17 |
| 2019-02-07      | Node   |          17.16 |
| 2019-02-10      | Node   |          17.17 |
```

Expected Result

```
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| Date(TimeStamp) | NodeName| CPUUtilization  |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| 2019-02-01      | Node   |          16.82 |
| 2019-02-02      | Node   |          16.84 |
| 2019-02-03      | Node   |          16.84 |
| 2019-02-04      | Node   |             17 |
| 2019-02-05      | Node   |             17 |
| 2019-02-06      | Node   |             17 |
| 2019-02-07      | Node   |          17.16 |
| 2019-02-08      | Node   |          17.16 |
| 2019-02-09      | Node   |          17.16 |
| 2019-02-10      | Node   |          17.17 |
```

Here, 2019-02-03 date record is missing.It has to copy the previous record data
as of '2019-02-02'?

Answer (score 0):

**Database Query**

```
SELECT Date(TimeStamp),NodeName,CPUUtilization 
from xyz WHERE timestamp BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE();
```

Comment: That's the same query as i posted in question